# C#. не Копируется Stream в MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте, есть ответ полученный для httpClient. Ответ считываю не в строку, а в поток (т.к. вся инфраструктура обмена данными работает с потоками). Этот поток нужно скопировать, но поток не копируется.

```
using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
{
    var outputBody = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    //DEBUG-------------
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(outputBody);
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();  //чтение полученного потока дает правильную строку.
    //DEBUG-------------

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    outputBody.CopyTo(memoryStream);   // копируем поток

    //DEBUG-------------
    reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
    text = reader.ReadToEnd();  // тут пустая строка!!!!!!!!!!!
    //DEBUG-------------

    return new MyHttpResponse { Body = memoryStream, StatusCode = response.StatusCode, Headers = response.Headers };
}
```

Не могу понять в чем дело?

Comment: а если поставить на 0 позицию перед MemoryStream. reader.Position = 0;

Comment: Position нету. FrameWork 4.5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> //DEBUG-------------
> StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(outputBody);
> string text = reader.ReadToEnd();  //чтение полученного потока дает правильную строку.
> //DEBUG-------------
> ```

Вот это удали, потому что уже нечего читать, когда всё прочитано.

> ```
> var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
> outputBody.CopyTo(memoryStream);   // копируем поток
> ```

После этого надо перемотать поток в начало:

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

> ```
> //DEBUG-------------
> reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
> text = reader.ReadToEnd();  // тут пустая строка!!!!!!!!!!!
> //DEBUG-------------
> ```

Если это оставить, то надо ещё раз добавить

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! думал поток только при Dispouse() очищает буфер.

Comment: @Aldmi, это, в общем-то, не очистка буфера.